# OSX won't search deep enough on external drive

Tags: macos, finder, ssd, search

When doing a search on my external drive (SSD) using Finder it only searches like 1, 2 or maybe 3 folders deep. I have to manually navigate deeper into folders, in order to increase my reach.

I can't find anything about this online. Any ideas?

Comment: Added, was in the tags but not desc. It's finder.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried rebuilding the Spotlight index?

This link to Apple support shows how to do it.

[Apple Support: How to rebuild the Spotlight index on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

Comment: We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the link you provided will answer the question.  Links can change and become outdated so we prefer the answers to not just be a link.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.

Comment: Have tried it but no dice. When I do navigate deeper into my folders, it will shift the depth I can search in. So it's not a matter of files not being found in general. It just won't go deeper than a few folders.